# Plot a function that gives a color

Tags: plotting, color

I have a function that takes in two numbers and returns a RGB color. I would like to plot that function on a 2D surface. How can I do that?

Comment: Where is the function?

Comment: [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html)?

Comment: @J. M. `ChromaticityPlot["RGB"]; {x, y, z} = 
 Interpolation[
    Thread[{Image``ColorOperationsDump``$wavelengths, #}]] & /@ 
  Transpose[Image``ColorOperationsDump``tris];`
  , `XYZClipped[S_, E_] := 
 NIntegrate[{x[l], y[l], z[l]}, {l, S, E}]/
  NIntegrate[x[l] + y[l] + z[l], {l, S, E}]`. The function I want to plot is `XYZColor[XYZClipped[S,E]]` from 400 to 700.

Comment: That returns an XYZ color, not an RGB color. You could probably use `Table[]` and `Image[]` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RegionPlot` with `ColorFunction`. It is important to use `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` otherwise your function will be given modified x and y values.

```
RegionPlot[
 True, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, GrayLevel@Norm[{x, y}]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 BoundaryStyle -> None
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If your color function is a linear interpolation based on some "sources" you can use [`VertexColors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexColors.html). The example from the documentation is

```
Graphics[Polygon[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}}, VertexColors -> {Red, Green, Blue}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And of course you can also sample your points and create an image manually. For example

```
pixels = Table[
   GrayLevel@Norm[{x, y}],
   {x, -1, 1, 0.01}, {y, -1, 1, 0.01}
   ];
Image[pixels]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]